# GraphQL arguments in child resolver

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm using `graphql-tools` and am testing a schema where both parent and child receive an argument.

```
{
  parentWithArg(a: "test") {
    childWithArg(b: "test")
  }
}
```

When the child resolver runs, I'm confused because the first argument contains `args`, which does not match the [spec](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers#Resolver-function-signature). The `obj` argument appears to be completely absent?

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
     parentWithArg(obj, args, ctx) {
        console.log('parentWithArg obj:', obj); // `{}` as expected
        return {
            childWithArg(obj, args, ctx) {
                console.log('childWithArg obj:', obj); // `{ b: 'test' }`
                return args.b; // null
            }
        };
    },
  },
};
```

Here is the example on Apollo Launchpad: https://launchpad.graphql.com/p08j03j8r0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens when you return a function for one of the properties in the object returned by a resolver -- GraphQL will call the function to resolve the value but it will only call it with three parameters instead of four (args, context and info). The parent or "root" value in this case is dropped because the function in this case is being called as part of resolving that very same root value.

To access the root value, your resolver for the `childWithArg` field should go under the resolvers for the `Parent` type, like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
     parentWithArg(obj, args, ctx) {
        return {}
    },
  },
  Parent: {
    childWithArg(obj, args, ctx) {
      console.log('childWithArg obj:', obj)
      return args.b
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel makes sense :) I can't find mention of this in Apollo or GQL docs though...

Comment: This looks like it.... https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/2eccaadfa95f3e50f5d0d1aba42c419a70c61fc5/src/execution/execute.js#L1259